# Allure steps descriptions cut in the report

Tags: allure

I am using Allure framework to generate reports for our tests. I annotated methods of my tests with `@Step` annotation from alllure, e.g.:

```
@Step("Openining page: {0}")
public void beforeNavigateTo(String url, WebDriver driver) {
```

However, in the report Allure steps are cut in the middle, e.g.:

> [16:51:42.647] Openining page: https://x.yyy.com/simplesaml/saml2/idp/SSOService.php?spentityid=https://neta...

I would like to see full step description so I can reproduce it.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `allure.max.title.length` system property to change maximum step title length.

Comment: Does it have to be set before the report is generated? Or it is used when rendering a report?

Comment: The property should be set on your project when you run the tests